# Angular when and how to release DOM to prevent memory leak?

Tags: angularjs, dom, memory, compilation

Angular newbie here. I have this custom directive that wraps a table row to show information of a tag. When I click 'edit' button in the row, the directive template will be changed and allow the user to update the tag name, when I click 'apply' button, the row will be changed back with the updated tag name, or if I click 'cancel edit' button, the row will be changed back too without any updates. So the editTag and cancelEditTag event function goes like this:

```
scope.editTag = function() {
    scope.originalTagName = scope.tag.name;
    element.html(getTemplate(true));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};
scope.cancelEditTag = function() {
    scope.tag.name = scope.originalTagName;
    element.html(getTemplate(false));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    scope.tagSubmitError = false;
    scope.errorMessage = '';
};
```

Yet when profiling this app using Chrome dev tool, I realized while switching on and off 'edit mode' by clicking 'edit' and 'cancel edit' button, the memory usage keeps climbing up(about 0.1-0.2mb each time), I think I've got a memory leak here, my guess is that after $compile, the old DOM hasn't been released? If so, how should I deal with it? If this is not the case, what else could be the troublemaker? Or is it not a memory leak at all? For the full context, below is the full code for my directive:

```
app.directive('taginfo', function($compile ,$http) {
var directive = {};
directive.tagSubmitError = true;
directive.errorMessage = '';
directive.originalTagName = '';
directive.restrict = 'A'; 
directive.scope = {
    tag : '=',
    selectedTagIds : '=selected',
};
function getTemplate(isEditing) {
    if (isEditing) {
        return '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectTag()" ng-checked="selectedTagIds.indexOf(tag.id) != -1"></th>' + 
                '<th>' + 
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.name" placeholder="请输入标签名称">' + 
                    '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 5px; " ng-show="tagSubmitError" ng-bind="errorMessage"></div>' + 
                '</th>' + 
                '<th><span class="label num-post"><%tag.num_items%></span></th>' + 
                '<th><button class="action-submit-edit" ng-click="submitEditTag()"><i class="icon-ok-2"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="action-cancel-edit" ng-click="cancelEditTag()"><i class="icon-ban"></i></button></th>';
    } else {
        return '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectTag()" ng-checked="selectedTagIds.indexOf(tag.id) != -1"></th>' + 
                '<th><%tag.name%></th>' +
                '<th><span class="label num-post"><%tag.num_items%></span></th>' +
                '<th><button class="action-edit" ng-click="editTag()"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="action-delete"><i class="icon-bin"></i></button></th>';
    }
}
directive.template = getTemplate(false);
directive.link = function(scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.selectTag = function() {
        var index = scope.selectedTagIds.indexOf(scope.tag.id);
        if (index == -1) {
            scope.selectedTagIds.push(scope.tag.id);
        } else {
            scope.selectedTagIds.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
    scope.submitEditTag = function() {
        if (scope.tag.name.length === 0) { 
            scope.tagSubmitError = true;
            scope.errorMessage = '请输入标签名称';
        } else {
            $http.post('/admin/posts/edit_tag', {'tagId': scope.tag.id, 'tagName': scope.tag.name}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.statusCode == 'error') {
                    scope.tagSubmitError = true;
                    scope.errorMessage = data.errorMessage;
                } else if (data.statusCode == 'success') {
                    scope.tag.name = data.tag_name;
                    scope.tagSubmitError = false;
                    scope.errorMessage = '';
                    element.html(getTemplate(false));
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    scope.editTag = function() {
        scope.originalTagName = scope.tag.name;
        element.html(getTemplate(true));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
    scope.cancelEditTag = function() {
        scope.tag.name = scope.originalTagName;
        element.html(getTemplate(false));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        scope.tagSubmitError = false;
        scope.errorMessage = '';
    };
};
return directive;
});
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr or jsfiddle? Thx

Comment: Here it is on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/815jeku2/10/
Just by click 'Edit tag' and 'Cancel edit' multiple times and you will see the memory usage keeps increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've figured a way to not compile directive template dynamically, thus to avoid memory usage climbing up. That is to add a boolean flag named 'isEditMode' which will be used in ng-if to decide which DOM to show, and the source code is follows:

```
app.directive('taginfo', function($http, $animate, listService) {
var directive = {};
directive.editTagSubmitError = false;
directive.errorMessage = '';
directive.originalTagName = '';
directive.restrict = 'A'; 
directive.isEditMode = false;
directive.scope = {
    tag : '=',
    pagination : '=',
    data : '='
};
directive.template = '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectTag()" ng-checked="data.selectedIds.indexOf(tag.id) != -1"></th>' + 
                '<th ng-if="isEditMode">' + 
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.name" placeholder="请输入标签名称">' + 
                    '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 5px; " ng-show="editTagSubmitError" ng-bind="errorMessage"></div>' + 
                '</th>' + 
                '<th ng-if="!isEditMode"><%tag.name%></th>' +
                '<th><span class="label num-posts"><%tag.num_items%></span></th>' + 
                '<th ng-if="isEditMode"><button class="action-submit-edit" ng-click="submitEditTag()"><i class="icon-ok-2"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="action-cancel-edit" ng-click="cancelEditTag()"><i class="icon-ban"></i></button></th>' +
                '<th ng-if="!isEditMode"><button class="action-edit" ng-click="editTag()"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="action-delete" ng-click="deleteTag()"><i class="icon-bin"></i></button></th>';
directive.link = function(scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.selectTag = function() {
        listService.selectEntry(scope.tag, scope.data);
    };
    scope.submitEditTag = function() {
        if (!scope.tag.name) { 
            scope.editTagSubmitError = true;
            scope.errorMessage = '请输入标签名称';
        } else {
            bootbox.confirm('是否确定修改标签名称为' + scope.tag.name +'？', function(result) {
                if (result === true) {
                    $http.post('/admin/posts/edit_tag', {'tagId': scope.tag.id, 'tagName': scope.tag.name}).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                        if (response.statusCode == 'error') {
                            scope.editTagSubmitError = true;
                            scope.errorMessage = response.errorMessage;
                        } else if (response.statusCode == 'success') {
                            scope.isEditMode = false;
                            scope.tag.name = response.tag_name;
                            scope.editTagSubmitError = false;
                            scope.errorMessage = '';
                            $animate.removeClass(element, 'editing');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
    scope.editTag = function() {
        scope.isEditMode = true;
        scope.originalTagName = scope.tag.name;
        if (!element.hasClass('editing')) {
            element.addClass('editing');
        }
    };
    scope.cancelEditTag = function() {
        scope.isEditMode = false;
        scope.tag.name = scope.originalTagName;
        scope.editTagSubmitError = false;
        scope.errorMessage = '';
    };
    scope.deleteTag = function() {
        listService.deleteEntry(scope.tag, scope.tag.name, scope.data, '/admin/posts/delete_tag', scope.pagination, 'tag');
    };
};
return directive;
```

});

This way, the directive template will not be compiled for editing/non-editing mode repeatedly but only show different DOM based on 'ng-if="isEditMode"'. It solved my problem. Yet I am still wondering if there's a way to remove memory leak for dynamic directive template compilation. Any thoughts would be appreciated.